# Not getting correct input form either scanf or printf in Nasm assembly program with menu

Tags: assembly, printf, nasm, scanf, x86-64

In the following, I'm trying to make it to where a user enters N and is prompte to enter an integer. Finally got that part working. I've spent a few hours trying to get the next part working. After they enter an integer, it goes back to the menu. For debugging purposes, if they enter F it should display the number that they entered. However, when entering N, then 3, then F, it displays 21505.

```
;nasm -f elf64 fib.asm -o fib.o
;gcc -S -masm=intel fib.c -o fib.s
;./fib




    bits 64
    global  main
    extern  puts
    extern  printf
    extern  scanf   
    extern  get_kb



section.data

errormsg:   db  'Invalid Input. Enter N,F, or X',0x0D,0x0a,0

numequalsmsg:   db  'Number equals: '

LC2:    db  "%d",0


menuprompt: db  0x0D,0x0a,'Enter N to enter an integer from 0 to 20',0x0D,0x0a,'Enter F to display the first N+1 numbers (beginning with zero) on the console',0x0D,0x0a,'Enter X to quit the program',0x0D,0x0a,0


choicemsg:  db  "Your Choice: ",0

LC5:    db  "%d",0


enterintmsg:    db  "Enter and integer 0-20: ",0


enternummsg:    db  'Enter a valid number between 0 and 20',0x0D,0x0a,0


LC8:    db  " , ",0
LC9:    db  'Success!',0x0D,0x0a,0
LC10:   db  'In L10!',0x0D,0x0a,0       
LC11:   db  'In L12!',0x0D,0x0a,0 
LC13:   db  'In compare to zero section',0x0D,0
value:  db  0
choice: db  1


.code
main:
    ;function setup 
    ;push   rbp
    ;mov    rbp, rsp
    ;sub    rsp, 16
    call menu

menu:
    ;print menu 
    mov edi, menuprompt
    call    puts            ;display menu
    mov edi,choicemsg
    ;mov    eax, 0
    ;call   printf          ;display "Your choice:" 
    call puts
    call    get_kb
    mov bl, al
    cmp bl, 'N' ;N
    je  read_int_new
    cmp bl, 'F' ;F
    je  fib
    cmp bl, 'X' ;X
    je  correct
    ;leave
    ;ret

    jmp menu
    ret





correct:
    mov edi, LC9
    mov eax,0
    call    printf
    jmp     menu
    ;leave  
    ;ret

entered_n:
    call    read_int_new
    ;jmp    correct 
    jmp menu
    ;leave
    ;jmp    menu 

read_int:
    mov edi, enterintmsg
    mov eax,0
    call    printf          

    ;mov    rdi, [LC5]
    ;mov    rsi, [value]
    ;xor    eax,eax

    ;add    esp,4       ;remove parameters
    ;push   rsi
    ;push   rdi 

    ;push   rbp
    ;mov    rax,0
    ;mov    rdi, LC5
    ;mov    rsi, value
    push value
    push LC5
    call    scanf
    add esp, 8  
   ;mov eax, value
    push value
    push LC5
    call printf
    add esp,8
    ;pop    rbp
    ;jmp    correct 
    ;mov cl, [value]
    ;jmp    menu
    ;leave
    ret


    ;leave  

read_int_new:
    ;push   rbp
    ;mov    rbp, rsp
    ;sub    rsp, 16


    mov edi, enterintmsg    ;display "Enter an integer 0-20: "
    mov eax, 0
    call    printf

    ;lea    rax, [value]
    ;mov    rsi, rax
    ;mov    edi, LC5
    ;mov    eax, 0
    ;call   scanf               ;get user input
    ;mov    ebx, [value]

    push value
    push LC5    
    call scanf
    mov esi, [value]

    mov edi, LC9            ;test to see if it got here
    mov eax, 0
    call    printf  


    ;test   ebx, ebx            ;compare to 0 (eax-eax=0)
    ;js L9
    ;mov    edi, LC9            ;test to see if it got here
    ;mov    eax, 0
    ;call   printf  

    ;mov    ebx, DWORD [rbp-4]
    ;cmp    ebx, 20             ;jump if greater than 20
    ;jg L9
    ;mov    edi, LC9            ;test to see if it got here
    ;mov    eax, 0
    ;call   printf      

    ;mov    ebx, DWORD [rbp-4]      ;else, jump to L10
    ;mov    edi, LC9            ;test to see if it got here
    ;mov    eax, 0
    ;call   printf      
    ;jmp    L10
    ;leave  
    ;ret
    jmp menu




fib:

    mov eax, esi    
    mov edi, LC5
    mov eax,0   
    ;mov eax, LC5
    ;push [eax] 
    ;push value
    ;push LC5    
    call printf
   jmp menu
```

Answer (score 0):

Code does not compile due to missing `get_kb`. Anyway, the commented out code in `read_int_new` is the correct one except for the `mov ebx, [value]`. If you change your `LC9` to actually print the number too (use a `%d`) then you can see the reading works.

If you also fix your `fib` by replacing `mov eax, esi` (which makes no sense whatsoever) with `mov esi, [value]` then the number will be correctly printed there too.

PS: learn to use a debugger.